# Problema com acentuação HTML e MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tendo uma série de problemas com acentuação, primeiro de tudo, estou usando WAMP Server. O charset do meu site está como UTF-8, isso porquê a ISO-xxx... simplesmente desconfigura toda a acentuação da página HTML, enfim, estou com duas fields no MySQL com acentuação que foram inseridas de um formulário do meu site e este foi o resultado:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx3aT2W0xcIpcWVHbkx4YjQwcmc/edit?usp=docslist_api

No meu site ao "ecoar" essas fields em um formulário de edição esse é o resultado:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx3aT2W0xcIpSWhmSS10YmlMcTQ/edit?usp=docslist_api
Como pode-se ver os erros de acentuação se foram.

Esses são os collations dessas fields:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx3aT2W0xcIpTXlQUUxFalpqRW8/edit?usp=docslist_api

Alguma idéia de como matar esse bug?

Comment: Já tentou usar `latin1_general_ci`?

Comment: Não, irei tentar.

Comment: Ultilizando UTF como encode vai assim para o banco, a não se que você utilize mb_encoding para salvar no banco, porem depois quando for exibir os regisitros tera que utilizar mb_encoding reverso

Comment: Rene Sá, sua sugestão funcionou. Valeu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de importar os dados para a sua base MySQL, defina um collation padrão. No Brasil o Latin1 é o mais utilizado, então o CHARSET (codificação de caracteres) padrão é o Latin1 e o COLLATE (collation) padrão é o `latin1_general_ci`. Scripts externos podem utilizar UTF8 e geralmente é por causa da diferença de codificação entre Latin1 e UTF8 que ocorrem erros de acentuação.

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = Latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci;
```

**OU**

```
ALTER DATABASE `sua_base` CHARSET = UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: (Alguém tem que responder)